# WoL Package succsessfully sent but PC won't start

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I have a problem with the WoL settings. I have already set in the BIOS to activate WoL and disable hibernate sleep. Also fast startup was disabled and the settings for the ehternet card to accept magic packets was set.

Long Story short:

I can't find any solution so far what setting I'm missing. 
I'm testing it with a PC beneath me. It's a DELL Optiplex, with WIN10 OS and a Intel Ethernet Card. WoL is supported by each one of them.

Comment: Did you set everything [recommended by DELL](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln292761/best-practices-zur-fehlerbehebung-bei-wake-on-lan-wol?lang=de)? As a sidenote: I deeply despise WoL, to get it working on different NICs, PCs, other equipment is a _nightmare_

Comment: I tried this also already but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Any components between the sender and the receiver of the magic packets? I had switches strip/alter/drop them from traffic.

Comment: I have a panel in between and one switch.